# making char pointer pointing to null causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault

in linux, I am trying the below code which is causing segmentation fault error:

```
int main(int arg_count,char *args[]){  
    char *buffer;
    if(arg_count>1)
      buffer = args[1];
    else 
      *buffer = 0;
 }
```

I know that pointers point to read only part of the memory, so I changed my first try `buffer[0]=0;` to above. But I don't understand why this one is not working either?!

Comment: You can't dereference a null pointer into anything meaningful.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Which null pointer?

Comment: @alk I believe he meant the "uninitialized pointer" => char *buffer;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The final line of your function, `*buffer = 0`, is attempting to set the value referred to by the pointer `buffer`.

As `buffer` has never been initialised and therefore contains an indeterminate value, dereferencing `buffer` is very likely to cause a segfault.

For most projects you should never write argument parsing code yourself. There are many robust and efficient libraries that will do a much better job than you (or I) could. As you are writing C on Linux [GNU getopt](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Parsing-Program-Arguments.html#Parsing-Program-Arguments) is a good option.

Comment: thank you. So in order to fix the problem, should I just initialize it to something(null for example)?

Comment: @TheEngineer maybe you should initialize it to NULL, but more important: you never should dereference un uninitialized pointer (neither a NULL pointer BTW).

Comment: `buffer = 0` of `buffer = NULL` would be both make sense. However, you must ensure that you do not dereference them elsewhere in your program.

Answer (score 1):

if you go through your program line by line you'll see that if the user doesn't pass any arguments then buffer is just a random value. As another comment said you need to initialize it. In your case I don't think you literally want to put the value `0` in the memory address that buffer points to. Here is code that shows how to handle arguments

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char *buffer = NULL;
    if(argc > 1){
        buffer = argv[1];
    }
    else{
        buffer = malloc(1024);
        puts("please enter an argument");
        fgets(buffer, 1024, stdin);
        //do stuff with buffer
        free(buffer)
    }
    return 0;
}
```

in the code above the program checks if any arguments were passed to the program, if no arguments were passed then the program allocated 1024 bytes and points buffer to that memory location and then asks the user for input. From this point you can do what ever you want with buffer.

Answer (score 0):

`buffer` character pointer is not initialised. Since `buffer` is declared with auto storage class it will have a garbage value. You are trying to access a uninitialized pointer which is a memory access exception hence it gave a seg fault. Before accessing `buffer` allocate a memory using calloc or malloc.